# Criar segunda coluna em DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ado.net

Tenho um `DataTable` onde com o código:

```
DT.Column.Add("1ª", gettype(int32))  
    For I = 1 To 30  
        DT.Rows.Add(I)  
    Next(I)
```

Este `For` enumera a coluna 1 de 1 a 30. 'DT está declarado com um novo `DataTable`, neste caso a prog faz tudo correto, mas eu gostaria de saber se é possivél eu adionar uma segunda coluna sem ser por meio de:

```
DT.Column.Add("1ª", gettype(int32))  
    For I = 1 To 30    
        DT.Rows.Add(I, I*2)    
    Next(I)
```

Isto seria necessário, pois a fórmula da segunda coluna varia de acordo com o valor de `I` em cada linha. Exemplos e/ou ajuda em C# são bem vindos.
*Trabalhar com linha eu domino relativamente bem, mas coluna é sempre uma dor de cabeça para mim.*

Tentei algo como:

```
For I = 1 To 30  
    DT.Rows.Add(I)  
Next(I)  
DT.Column.Add("2ª", gettype(int32))
For I = 1 to 30
  DT.Rows.Add(I)
Next(I)
```

Mas sem êxito algum, ele apenas cria a coluna 2 e acrescenta dados a coluna 1.

Comment: Não entendi o objetivo. É criar uma segunda coluna ou colocar dados nela?

Comment: @jbueno preciso popular a segunda coluna com base nos dados da primeira. Popular inúmeras colunas por vez (código 2) é tranquilo, mas o que preciso é realmente escrever um código que permita popular a segunda coluna com limitações a primeira. Exemplo:  Quando houver um `I>10` ele fará na segunda coluna `I/2`. Ficou mais claro o objetivo?

Comment: Perai, tô processando hehe

Comment: @jbueno Tens tempo, se quiseres podes olhar a resposta do Filipe é de repente tentar ajudar-me mais ainda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi bem o que você quer, provavelmente a solução é fazer dessa forma:

```
DataTable DT = new DataTable();
DT.Columns.Add("1ª", typeof(int));
DT.Columns.Add("2ª", typeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    var row = DT.NewRow();
    row["1ª"] = i;
    row["2ª"] = i;
    DT.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Ou dessa:

```
DataTable DT = new DataTable();
DT.Columns.Add("1ª", typeof(int));
DT.Columns.Add("2ª", typeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    DT.Rows.Add(i, i);
}
```

Comment: eu uso VB.NET tentei traduzir o código que você apresentou, cheguei ao seguinte: ` For I = 1 And I > 10 To 30  
                    DT.Rows.Add(I, I / 2)  
                Next (I)`, Ele popula a segunda porém ele começa dividindo tudo já, mas pelo menos já é um começo obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @AlexNunes, o `I` vai começar igual para ambos, talvez deva mudar a lógica da iteração para que atenda ao que precisa.